# Recursive Function - what is going on here?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have been reading Eloquent Javascript and came across this code which results in 32.  I simply have no idea how it comes to that number though.  I am trying to wrap my head around this.  So 2 is the base and 5 is the exponent, 2* power(2,5 -1)  <----what does that -1 signify?  Thanks for all your help:

```
function power(base, exponent) {
  if (exponent == 0)
    return 1;
  else
    return base * power(base, exponent - 1);
}

console.log(power(2, 5));
```

Comment: Do you understand any other recursive function?

Comment: `5 - 1` signifies `4`

Answer (score 1):

This works like this: if we want to get `base ^ 0`, then we have 1. This is the if statement. Otherwise, this function is going to calculate `base * base ^ (exponent - 1)`. See, for example, `2 ^ 3 = 2 * 2 ^ 2`. It will continue unwrapping this exponents until we reach point zero - `2 * 2 * 2 * 2 ^ 0` is the same as `2 * 2 * 2`, and we defined `2 ^ 1` to return 1.

Answer (score 0):

That's called recursion! What's happening is that base * power will return the base the amount of times that was passed as exponent (Less 1 since the original base already is there).

What in that case ends up is 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 1 (Since it stops the last time when the exponent is now 0.

If you want more info, read about recursion in programming https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I had one more question - why when I take the -1 does it say: Maximum call stack size in the console.  

I understand I created an infinite loop, but how?  I assume the -1 is due to the fact that js is zero-indexed.  There is an if statement that states if it is 0, return 1

Does that not prevent the infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comment, `5-1` evaluates to `4`. So

```
 2 * power(2,5 -1)
```

evaluates to

```
 2 * power(2, 4)
```

This should make sense when you think about exponents. If we use `^` as the exponent operator, then the recursive function is using the identity

```
2^5 = 2 * 2^4
```

which is mathematically true. The code evaluates `2^4` and multiples the result by `2` to get `2^5`.

Answer (score 0):

It's looping you can fill in the blanks to see what is happening, it loops 6 times (5 to 0)

It might be easier to work backwards

- Last loop returns 1
- add to Second loop returns 2 * 1
- Third loop returns 2 * 2 * 1
- Fourth loop returns 2 * 2 * 2 * 1
- fifth loop returns 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 1
- sixth loop returns 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 1

It's a confusing because you would never use a recursive function like this in real life, it's far more efficient to solve iteratively.